# Relation between B-spline curve and its control polygon if either of them would be convex

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, bezier-curve, spline

would you please discuss the following statement : 
"If control polygon of a B-spline curve is convex then B-spline curve is also convex".

Comment: would you please discuss what you have already tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think this comes from the "variation diminishing property" of B-spline curves, which means any line will not intersect the curve more times than it intersects the control polygon. Here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_diminishing_property) for more details.